# Which layout to use for process flow dependency using d3.js for large number of nodes

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, d3.js

I am newbie to d3. I have a requirement in which I need to visualize process flow dependency. 
These dependencies may or may not be cyclic. I have more than 5000 processes which can be dependent up to a depth 40 or more. For example:

```
Process A --> (Process B,Process E) -->Process C -- and so on can be as deep as 40 nodes.
Process B --> Process D
Process C ---> (Process D,Process F)
Process D --> (Process A, Process E)
Process F
```

I am able to do this as a tree layout. Something similar to (http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).In this case I am breaking the cyclic dependency and outputting same node multiple times.
But having ~5000 nodes makes graph huge it very non-intuitive to understand and searching for a particular node is even tougher. 
Any ideas what kind of tree/graph should I use for this kind of situation. 
I am looking into some of the examples in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery . Any pointers will regarding this will be very useful.

Comment: what did you end up doing for this?  I'm facing a similar problem and was also looking at the d3js tree concept and representing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/

It is from same gallery link which you provided. This is based on idea of adjacency matrix and Design Structure Matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_structure_matrix